# I have string containing "/" character. how could i delete the line having this string in sed?

Tags: sed

I have a file named abc.txt with below content.

```
838929po/83738 ijwiwj
dkljqdk
dmwqdwq
```

then I assign the first pattern to a variable.

```
var=`cat abc.txt | head -n1 | cut -f1 -d' '`
```

then I use $var to delete the line in sed as below.

```
sed ';'$var';d' abc.txt > abc1.txt
```

But I am getting below error.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: extra characters after command
```

It is because of "/" character in $var.

Can anybody help how can I delete the line. I have to use $var at any cost.